# emcc won't run on Mac OSX 10.15, clang-10: error unknown argument: '-fignore-exceptions'

Tags: c, llvm, webassembly, emscripten, emcc

I have a simple `hello.c` file with the following contents:

```
#include <emscripten.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("hello wasm\n");
}
```

I am trying to compile this into a `.html` with emscripten `emcc` command using:

`emcc hello.c --emrun -o hello.html`

But the output that I get is:

`emcc: warning: LLVM version appears incorrect (seeing "10.0", expected "11.0") [-Wversion-check]
clang-10: error: unknown argument: '-fignore-exceptions'
emcc: error: '/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -target wasm32-unknown-emscripten -D__EMSCRIPTEN_major__=1 -D__EMSCRIPTEN_minor__=39 -D__EMSCRIPTEN_tiny__=18 -D_LIBCPP_ABI_VERSION=2 -Dunix -D__unix -D__unix__ -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Xclang -nostdsysteminc -Xclang -isystem/usr/local/Cellar/emscripten/1.39.18/libexec/system/include/compat -Xclang -isystem/usr/local/Cellar/emscripten/1.39.18/libexec/system/include -Xclang -isystem/usr/local/Cellar/emscripten/1.39.18/libexec/system/include/libc -Xclang -isystem/usr/local/Cellar/emscripten/1.39.18/libexec/system/lib/libc/musl/arch/emscripten -Xclang -isystem/usr/local/Cellar/emscripten/1.39.18/libexec/system/local/include -Xclang -isystem/usr/local/Cellar/emscripten/1.39.18/libexec/system/include/SSE -Xclang -isystem/usr/local/Cellar/emscripten/1.39.18/libexec/cache/wasm/include -DEMSCRIPTEN -fignore-exceptions hello.c -Xclang -isystem/usr/local/Cellar/emscripten/1.39.18/libexec/system/include/SDL -c -o /var/folders/74/19dk0c293ps0fmfj5vsqld1w0000gn/T/emscripten_temp_xakv8jzi/hello_0.o -mllvm -combiner-global-alias-analysis=false -mllvm -enable-emscripten-sjlj -mllvm -disable-lsr' failed (1)`

I have emscripten and dependencies installed via homebrew. These are the necessary exports in my `.zshrc` are :

`export LLVM="/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin"
 export BINARYEN="/usr/local/opt/binaryen/bin"`

How can I get this to work?

Comment: Did you restart the shell so the environment variables got set?

Comment: It appears you need to upgrade the Xcode that you have installed.  The version you have is too old (10.0) instead of what is expected (11.0 — or later).

Answer (score 3):

emscripten requires llvm tip of tree (11).   Its not compatible with LLVM 10 or any other stable version.  The simplest way to install emscripten along with a compatible version of llvm is to use emsdk to install rather than homebrew.

Comment: This is unfortunate. Was there any version of Emscripten that worked with Clang 10?